# Why the fetch json api appears errors

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have some problem with Json.

1. When I click json file, the browser or code editor just freeze.
2. I create three array variable, but every time i push the item the browser just appeared ....push is not a function or give me the wrong answer.

The example is down below:

first lets assume the json format is like this:

```js
//json file

[[{"id":1,"status":'idle',"runTimeStart":121212,"runTimeFinished":12121212},{"id":2,"status":'idle',"runTimeStart":121212,"runTimeFinished":12121212},{"id":3, "status":'idle',"runTimeStart":121212,"runTimeFinished":12121212}]];
```

```js
//I create three array

var status = [];
var runtimeStart = [];
var runtimeFinished = [];         


fetch('data.json')
.then(data=> data.json())
.then(res=> allData(res))

//Main function is here 

function allData(lop) {
  var long = lop[0];
  for(var i = 0; i <  long.length; i++) {
   runtimeStart.push(long[i].runTimeStart);
   console.log(long[i].runTimeStart);
   console.log(long[i].status);
   console.log(long[i].runTimeFinished);
   status.push(long[i].status);
   console.log(status);
   runtimeStart.push(long[i].runTimeStart);
   console.log(runtimeStart);
   console.log(runtimeStart);
  }
}
```

You can see the code upon this text, so when i just log out the format like: console.log(long[i].status). The browser will freeze for a while, but the result still log out status.

But when i do something like this: status.push(long[i].status); console.log(status);   it says push is not a function.

I am really confused why the result appear errors, hope you guys can help me out, thank you so much!

Comment: so, is your question: `But when i do something like this: status.push(long[i].status); console.log(status); it says push is not a function`

Comment: I see that the array in json you've referred to as `long` ... just how BIG is the array (i.e. what is `long.length`)

Comment: Yes, that s my problem. I just randomly named it. The json contains 112 items.

Comment: try using a *different name* for `status` ... or make your code NOT in the global context ... because `window.status` is a thing already - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some variable names you should avoid in a browser

e.g., `status` in the global context is probably being "messed up" by [window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status)

other ones are `name`, `origin`, `length`, `innerWidth`, `screenX` etc etc - in fact if you `console.log(window)` and drill down all the prototype chain of the output, they would be the names to avoid

Two options

change

```
var status = [];
status.push(....);
```

etc

to

```
var _status = [];
_status.push(....);
```

or some other change

or, put that code inside a function

```
function whatever() {
    var status = [];
    ...
    status.push(.....);
}
```

This possibly explains the "freezing" too

Comment: Thank you so much. Its improve a lot, but when i log out the length of status array, originally it should appear 112. But why the result is something like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11........and so on. Until 112 then it will stop.

Comment: @Michaelwang - you have 112 items as you say in your JSON ... the console.log is after you push each one ... so after the first, 1 will be output, then 2 ... all the way up to the 112ths, which console.logs 112 - I don't see why this confuses you. How can the array be 112 long after you push ONE element to it?

Comment: The goal is changed, this is new question. The status push works totally fine, just change another question, so please dont misunderstand

Comment: yeah, right ... but what is the question now? Why you get the length of the array output after you push each element? because that's what your code does

Comment: NO.....i want to 112 length appear on the console. But the console appears 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5, 6......and so on until 112. The series appear in the console, not the single 112 itself

Comment: right ... logging arrays and objects to the console can be confusing because the console evaluates the array at the time you view it ... I usually do something like `console.log(array.slice())` that way I get the output of an array that wont change later

Comment: OH, i think i found out the solution if i console.log the item within the for loop, definitely will appear error. But i test it outside of the for loop, it returns single value. Ok, thank you for spending the time with me to solve the problem. Thank you so much!